# MODX Minishop2 Корзина. Как преобразовать формат даты?

Tags: modx, minishop2

Не могу корректно вывести дату публикации товара(Ресурса) В корзине. Корзина реализована через minishop2. Дата выводится везде корректно, кроме корзины. Вместо даты я получаю просто набор цифр. К примеру, дата публикации 25.12.2018 в корзине выводится как 1545686640. Пробывал выводить вот так:

```
{$product.publishedon}
```

Я отдебажил весь массив, и увидел, что в publishedon дата действительно хранится в таком формате. Видимо, мне нужно как то преобразовать ее. Как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Преобразовать дату и время в `modx` можно либо встроенным модификатором, например:

`{set $product.publishedon = '1545686640'}
{$product.publishedon | date: 'd.m.Y'} // 25.12.2018`

либо, например сниппетом [DateAgo](https://modstore.pro/packages/utilities/dateago), который в отличии от встроенного может принимать как `unix timestamp`, так и строку с датой:

`{$product.publishedon | date_format: '%d.%m.%Y'} // 25.12.2018`